# Cleanly converting a {"key" => ["val1", "val2"]} hash into a {"key" => "val1", "key" => "val2"} hash in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm fairly new to Ruby/Rails, and I'm trying to figure out how to split a `{"key" => ["val1", "val2"]}` hash into a `{"key" => "val1", "key" => "val2"}` hash. I feel like I should flatten the hash and somehow build a new one up, but I'm unsure how to approach the problem. Thanks!

EDIT: Haha, shows how blinded I was by the trees to not see the forest. Can't believe I made such a silly mistake. Thanks to everyone who shook me awake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Hash by definition cannot have the same key present more than once. Would you instead like an Array of arrays?

```
[['key','val1'],['key','val2']]
```

If so, and if every hash key is an array of values, then you can do this:

```
devalues = { a:[1,2,3], b:[4], c:[5,6] }
exploded = devalues.map{ |k,vs| ([k]*vs.length).zip(vs) }.flatten(1)
p exploded
#=> [[:a, 1], [:a, 2], [:a, 3], [:b, 4], [:c, 5], [:c, 6]]
```

*Note that `flatten(1)` is Ruby 1.8.7+ only*

**Edit**: Per Nakilon's comment below, this can be a hair simpler [in Ruby 1.9.2+](http://swik.net/Ruby/Code+Snippets%3a+ruby/Introducing+the+new+Ruby+1.9.2+Array,+and+Enumerable+methods/eb7c5):

```
exploded = devalues.flat_map{ |k,vs| ([k]*vs.length).zip(vs) }
```

**Edit**: Or per @tokland's comment below, even shorter/better using [`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-product):

```
exploded = devalues.flat_map{ |k,vs| [k].product(vs) }
```

Comment: Thanks, key parts of my brain have turned to mush and I obviously lost sight of something very obvious. Thanks!

Comment: In 1.9.x Rube you may use `.flat_map` instead of `.map.flatten(1)`

Comment: @Nakilon What a bizarre-but-common method. Thanks for sharing. [Here are the docs on it](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001492) for future explorers.

Comment: OMG, i wrote Rub**E** ..D So sad, it's unable to edit old comments ))

Comment: @Nakilon it's ok, my fingers too are often treasonous homonym transcription devices.

Comment: even more concise: h.flat_map { |k, vs| [k].product(vs) }

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have duplicate keys in a `Hash`.

Also, why in the world would you want to do this? IMHO the way you have it now is perfectly fine.

Comment: Long story where I've melted my brain by thinking in the wrong direction for too long. Thanks for pointing out my bizarre thinking.